# Collada Export confusion

Tags: animation, export, collada

I make a simple animation in Blender and export to Collada format. Everything looks the way I would hope for. There is 1 <animation> for each bone consisting of input/output/interpolation arrays.

If i happen use 'Action Editor' Mode in the DopeSheet view, the same blend file now exports many more <animation> to the dae file.  Each bone now also has location(x/y/z) input/output arrays  and  scale(x/y/z) input/output arrays.

Why does simply selecting the 'Action Editor' mode in 'Dope Sheet' view introduce all the new <animation> in the .dae file?

Is there a way to stop that? It was my understanding that transform matrix can take care of all 3 (TransLocRot).